# What is the proper way to add a database.mdf to an N-Tier winforms application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework

I have the following application architecture and I am using EF6:

`TartanModel <-> TartanGenerator.DAL <-> TartanGenerator.BLL <-> Winforms Application`

The EDMX file is located in the DAL and the entities for the EDMX are in the model. I keep getting the following error:

> {"The underlying provider failed on Open."}

I have tried multiple connection strings for my application.config file which ended up looking like the following, and keep getting the same error:

```
<add name="TartanIndexEntities" connectionString="
    metadata=
        res://*/TartanModel.csdl|
        res://*/TartanModel.ssdl|
        res://*/TartanModel.msl;
    provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
    provider connection string=&quot;
        Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
        AttachDBFilename=TartanIndex.mdf;
        Database=TartanIndex
        Integrated Security=True;
        User Instance=True;
        MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
        App=EntityFramework&quot;"
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Originally the MDF File was attached to MSSQL Server v2014 with the following connection string:

```
<add name="TartanIndexEntities" connectionString="
    metadata=
        res://*/TartanModel.csdl|
        res://*/TartanModel.ssdl|
        res://*/TartanModel.msl;
    provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=TartanIndex;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

What I am needing to do, is place the MDF and LDF files in a data directory (maybe use the `|DataDirectory|` parameter in the connection string) in the main application folder so I can create an installshield application installer for this application.

1. Where should the files go?
2. What is the correct Connection String?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

I ended up having to have to:

1. Rebuild the log file.
2. Delete all occurrences of the database and log files from my system except the correct database file.
3. Changed my Connection string to the following:

   ```
   <add name="TartanIndexEntities" connectionString="
       metadata=
           res://*/TartanModel.csdl|
           res://*/TartanModel.ssdl|
           res://*/TartanModel.msl;
       provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
       provider connection string=&quot;
           Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
           Integrated Security=True;
           AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|TartanIndex.mdf;
           App=EntityFramework&quot;"
   providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
   ```

   4. Placed the Database and Log files into my Model.

All works and the application is allot faster than going through my dev MSSQL Server.